# CLion supported toolchain versions

Tags: c++, c, clion, jetbrains-ide

After some research, I figured SO is the site to ask this question.

When using CLion, I am using the latest compilers and debuggers in my projects, however, there is absolutely no information about which toolchain versions that CLion supports (except for some 2016, 2019 answers online, but CLion is updated frequently).

The only way to learn is to install the latest version possible (for example `10.2`), and then and only then, I can see a string such as `Only supported versions 8.x-9.x.`. But I compile/install some of these tools. I don't want to go through a 45 minutes compilation process just to discover it is unsupported, and I should have compiled an older version. I can't find this information anywhere, and it changes with each update.

**I apologize:** I am adding `c`/`c++` as tags, because the frequent users of CLion IDE might have more information about this rather then the subscribers of the `clion` tag.

Comment: I'm not a clion user, but I'd be surprised if the IDE cares much (I'd expect it to build using cmake or something similar).  Are you sure it's clion complaining about toolchain versions?

Comment: @StephenNewell Yes, it warns when tried to be used with unsupported versions. I avoid it to prevent undefined behaviors (it has CMake version constraints as well).

Comment: This seems like a question you should ask on JetBrains' forum: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200363649-CLion

Comment: @MichaelBurr You are correct, I will ask there as well. But I will keeps this here too. I should use all options to get the information I need.

Comment: For compilation, there should be absolutely no real requirements -- since this all delegates to the compiler used in the build commands, which are all generated by CMake. The "toolchain requirements" are otherwise only there to ensure that CLion can integrate correctly with the tooling. Certain CMake features are needed for the IDE to behave correctly, and minimum debugger versions are required so that the IDE can integrate into the debugger to send the correct commands.

Comment: @Human-Compiler You are right about compilation. This version issue usually affects tools associated with, debugging, auto-correct, valgrind, cmake features, etc. So still a considerable impact on development quality.

Answer (score 0):

The information about supported toolchains could be found in CLion Help and [release notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=206537854)

- [Windows toolchains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html)
- [MacOS toolchains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-macos.html)
- [Debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/clion-quick-start-guide.html#debugging)

The [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-create-toolchain-in-clion.html) is a good starting point to find useful information about the versions.